# GCP logging with json appender for sping boot app

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-logging, spring-logback, spring-cloud-gcp

I am trying adding gcp trace and logging to spring boot app but I get this error

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:
Parameter 1 of constructor in com.google.cloud.spring.logging.LoggingWebMvcConfigurer required a bean of type  com.google.cloud.spring.core.GcpProjectIdProvider that could not be found.
Action:
Consider defining a bean of type com.google.cloud.spring.core.GcpProjectIdProvider in your configuration.

in gradle.build, I added the dependencies

```
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-autoconfigure:1.1.0.RELEASE'
implementation 'com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-logging:2.0.0'
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-trace:1.2.5.RELEASE'
```

and in application.properties

```
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
spring.cloud.gcp.logging.enabled=true
spring.sleuth.sampler.probability=1.0
```

in logback-spring.xml I have this configurations

```
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml" />
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml" />

    <springProfile name="dev |tcm | ver | prd">
        <!--include resource="com/google/cloud/spring/logging/logback-json-appender.xml"/-->
        <property name="projectId" value="${projectId:-${GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT}}"/>
        <appender name="CONSOLE_JSON" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
            <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
                <layout class="com.google.cloud.spring.logging.StackdriverJsonLayout">
                    <!--projectId>${projectId}</projectId-->

                    <!--<includeTraceId>true</includeTraceId>-->
                    <!--<includeSpanId>true</includeSpanId>-->
                    <!--<includeLevel>true</includeLevel>-->
                    <!--<includeThreadName>true</includeThreadName>-->
                    <!--<includeMDC>true</includeMDC>-->
                    <!--<includeLoggerName>true</includeLoggerName>-->
                    <!--<includeFormattedMessage>true</includeFormattedMessage>-->
                    <!--<includeExceptionInMessage>true</includeExceptionInMessage>-->
                    <!--<includeContextName>true</includeContextName>-->
                    <!--<includeMessage>false</includeMessage>-->
                    <!--<includeException>false</includeException>-->
                    <!--<serviceContext>
                          <service>service-name</service>
                          <version>service-version</version>
                        </serviceContext>-->
                    <!--<customJson>{"custom-key": "custom-value"}</customJson>-->
                </layout>
            </encoder>
        </appender>
        <root level="INFO">
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE_JSON"/>
        </root>
    </springProfile>
</configuration>
```

anyone had similar issue and managed to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

These dependencies' versions are not mutually consistent:  `com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-logging:2.0.0`, `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-autoconfigure:1.1.0.RELEASE` and `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-trace:1.2.5.RELEASE`.

Use the same version for all three dependencies -- the latest is `3.1.0`. Also notice that between 1.x and 2.x+, the group and package names changed to `com.google.cloud`.